# Python Global Variables Confusion

Tags: python, variables, global

I have some VB code that I'm trying to replicate in Python, but I'm new to Python and its handling of global variables has me completely confused.

I have a Python script (pytSettings) that imports text from a text file and assigns portions of the text to various string variables.  Example...

```
def main(): 
    strFileS = "/Users/username/Desktop/settings.txt"
    fileHandleS = open(strFileS, 'r')
    fileContentsS = fileHandleS.readlines()
    fileHandleS.close()

    strPhotoInclude = fileContentsS[0]
```

Then, I have a second script (pytBatch) that loops through the lines of a separate text file and assigns portions of each line of text to a different set of string variables.  Within this second script (pytBatch), I need access to the variables from the first script (pytSettings).

Complicating matters, within the While loop of the second script (pytBatch), I call a third script (pytGenerate) that needs access to string variables from the first and second scripts.

```
def main():    
    strFileB = "/Users/username/Desktop/batch.txt"
    fileHandleB = open(strFileB, 'r')
    fileContentsB = fileHandleB.readlines()
    fileNumLines = len([l for l in fileContentsB if l.strip(' \n') != ''])
    fileHandleB.close

    icnt = 0
    while icnt < (fileNumLines):
        fileHandleB = open(strFileB, 'r')
        fileLine = fileHandleB.readlines()
        strLineTemp = fileLine[icnt]
        strLineTempI = strLineTemp.find("|")
        strPhotoLocation = strLineTemp[0:strLineTempI]
        if strPhotoLocation == "NullField":
            strPhotoInclude = "FALSE"
        else:
            strPhotoInclude = strPhotoInclude

        pytGenerate.main()

        icnt = icnt +1
```

In the example above:

1. strPhotoInclude is set in the pytSettings script.
2. strPhotoLocation is set in the pytBatch script
3. If strPhotoLocation = "NullField", strPhotoInclude is then set to "FALSE"
4. strGenerate is called, with both strPhotoInclude and strPhotoLocation being used in that code (not shown because until I can successfully learn how to get the variables from pytSettings to pytBatch, scripting pytGenerate is useless)
5. pytBatch then resumes and loops through the next icnt iteration

I've read dozens of threads on global variable and tried placing the global declaration in any number of places, but I just can't get the sequencing correct.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

EDIT to ADD:

OK.  That got me over the first hurdle, but the call to the third file is causing a related problem.

In the second file, there's a loop that sets several global variables, runs the third script, then loops through another iteration in the second script to reset the variables, then re-runs the third script.

```
import pytSettings
pytSettings_main()

def main():
    '''code that loads the text file omitted'''
    global strPhoto
    icnt = 0
    while icnt < (fileNumLines):
        strPhoto = strLineTemp
        '''reset photo include to false if photo if no photo filename provided'''
        if strPhoto == "NullField":
            pytSettings.strPhotoInclude = "FALSE"
        else:
            pytSettings.strPhotoInclude = "TRUE"

    '''call the Generate script'''
    pytGenerate.main()

    '''iterate to next line of the input text file'''
    icnt = icnt +1
```

My third script (pytGenerate) can't find the globals from the second script (pytBatch), but can find them from the first (pytSettings).

```
import pytSettings
import pytBatch

def main():
    print pytSettings.strMarginTop '''this works'''
    print pytBatch.strPhoto        '''this does not'''
```

The attempt to reference the second script's global variable (strPhoto) results in "'module' has no attribute 'strPhoto'".

Comment: Don't replicate code, replicate algorithms.

Comment: You can't access variables from one script in another without importing them.

Comment: What do you mean by "script"?  Are these completely separate programs that are run independently?  Are they python modules that are all used together within a single program?

Comment: Sorry... forgot to include the imports when I trimmed out a lot of the code for posting.  I have a line in the second script (pytBatch) importing the first (pytSettings), and a line in the third importing both.

When I say script, they're separate py files.  The code will be several thousand lines long, and I'm attempting to keep it in manageable smaller pieces.  I'm basically attempting to duplicate VB subroutines and calls, so if there's a better way I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

In a function, you need to declare the variable as global first:

```
>>> def some_function():
>>>     global x
>>>     x = 5
>>> x # before executing f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

>>> f()
>>> x # after executing f()
5
```

With multiple files it's essentially the same, except variables are also namespaced by the file:

**file1:**

```
## py1.py
def main():
    global x
    x = 10
```

**file2:**

```
## py2.py
import py1
py1.main()
print py1.x
```

Comment: OK.  I see what I was missing.  In file2, I was omitting the file1 name prior to the variable. (for example, I was typing "print x" instead of "print py1.x")  Thanks Nisan!